# script to zip a file and change it's owenrships

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script I am working on that reads off of a text file and will use the information stored in the text file to put each line entered in as an array. This array is a reference to files that are imported to a directory in another script. The problem is i built a function to zip the contents of the directory and change it's ownerships, but when I run the script it was zipping and attempting to change ownerships of the `pwd`. Here is my code below:

```
file=~/exporttool/zipFiles.txt
index=0
declare -a studyinstanceuids
while read line ; do
        studyinstanceuids[$index]="$line"
        index=$((index+1))
        echo $line
done < $file
for i in "${studyinstanceuids[@]}"
do
echo "$i" | ./cmd2;
done
echo "Exams are in!";

##Function with argument that will take prompt to change ownerships
echo "What is the name of the owner: "
read $owner

zipForOwner(){
        arg1=$1
        for i in "${studyinstanceuids[@]}"; do
                zip -r ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/20140620_"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip .
                sudo chown $1:$1 ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip
                sudo mv ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip ~/home/"$1"
        done
}

zipForOwner $owner
exit;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions

EDIT: Heere are my results running in xterm

```
+ file=/home/support/exporttool/zipFiles.txt
+ index=0
+ declare -a studyinstanceuids
+ read line
+ studyinstanceuids[$index]=1.3.46.670589.16.11.8.34254330145.20140603.134057.0
+ index=1
+ echo 1.3.46.670589.16.11.8.34254330145.20140603.134057.0
1.3.46.670589.16.11.8.34254330145.20140603.134057.0
+ read line
+ for i in '"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"'
+ echo 1.3.46.670589.16.11.8.34254330145.20140603.134057.0
+ ./cmd2
Please enter StudyInstanceUID:
+ echo 'Exams are in!'
Exams are in!
+ echo 'What is the name of the owner: '
What is the name of the owner:
+ read
sftpuser
+ zipForOwner
+ arg1=
+ for i in '"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"'
+ zip -r /home/support/export/1.3.46.670589.16.11.8.34254330145.20140603.134057.0/20140620_1.3.46.670589.16.11.8.34254330145.20140603.134057.0.zip .
  adding: .studiesToExportSend.txt.swp^C


zip error: Interrupted (aborting)
+ sudo chown : /home/support/export/1.3.46.670589.16.11.8.34254330145.20140603.134057.0/1.3.46.670589.16.11.8.34254330145.20140603.134057.0.zip
[sudo] password for support:
```

Comment: Run the script with `bash -x ./scriptname` to see exactly what it's trying to do.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that, I just tried running it on my work's server because I felt confident enough that it may work and the thing went crazy!

Comment: The `-x` option enabled `xtrace` which outputs each and every command as it runs it.  It will produce a buttload of output but it's the best way to see what the script is doing vs what you expect it to do.  Maybe make some dummy data to test it with?

Comment: I think the problem is from the zip command in my function.

Comment: The zip function looks ok (except you interrupted it).  The real problem is `sudo chown : `.  Did you forget to pass argument one (`$1`)?  It looks like it's supposed to be a username.  Example: `./scriptname.sh username`

Comment: In my script I prompted the username and passed that off as the argument when I called the function though

Comment: The problem is definately with zipping the file btw, I see it in the xtrace when I used it. That file it was attempting to zip is in my present directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
zip -r ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/20140620_"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip .
```

You're attempting to create a zip file called `~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/20140620_"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip` (good) with all of the contents in the *current directory* `.` (bad).

You need to change the `.` to be the folder you want zipped.

Comment: I think that's the problem.